# Why it is not redirecting

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
<?php 

  if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){

    $name = $db->validation($_POST['name']);

    $id = "";
    for($i= strlen($name) ; $i>=1 ; $i--){
         if($name[$i-1] == 'a'){
               break;
            }else{
          $id = $id.$name[$i-1];
       }    
    }
    $userid =  strrev($id);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bluekolar_user WHERE token = '$name' AND user_id='$userid'";
    $result = $db->select($query);
    if($result){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) ==1 ){
            $qu = "UPDATE bluekolar_user SET active = '1' WHERE user_id='$userid'";
            $res = $db->update($qu);
            if($res){
                $url = "profile/index.php?id=".$userid ;
                header('location:'.$url) ;
                exit();
            }else{
                $error = "Provide correct confirmation code";
            }
        }else{
            $error = "Provide correct confirmation code";
        }
    }

  }

 ?>
```

The code is performing good but it is unable to redirect. I don't know why. I need help.
Please help me so that I can redirect my code command to another page.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you get an HTTP status code like 404 or some other problem?

Comment: No, when I submit the sql query perform as I want but the page can not redirect. It take place where it is.

Comment: So to clarify: you're saying the `UPDATE` query is performed successfully but the page will still not redirect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the path you are trying to redirect to is correct.  The code in your question will try to redirect to a "profile" subdirectory of the location where this script is running.  If you want to go to "http://example.com/profile/index.php?id=" you need to change your $url to be "/profile/index.php"

Comment: Then how can I use "id?=" in url

Comment: Replace   `$url = "profile/index.php?id=".$userid ;`   with    `$url = "/profile/index.php?id=".$userid ;`    (Notice the leading `'/'` within the quotes.)

Comment: BTW, when using fixed strings containing no embedded variables, you should use single quotes rather than double quotes so the PHP interpreter doesn't have to parse the string, i.e., use `$url = 'profile/index.php?id='.$userid;` rather than `$url = "profile/index.php?id=".$userid;`

Comment: @nazmul_94_hasan did this fix your problem?  If so, can you mark it as the accepted answer?